# Why the max can be found only with normalized vectors?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Can someone explain why the term in the first `{}` equals the second term in the `{}` :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the norm of $\frac{x}{\| x \|}$? Then use the scalar-linearity of the mapping $x\mapsto Ax$.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\in K^n$ there is a normalized vector $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$; using the axioms for  matrixnorms we have $\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\|=\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$

Therefore, it is sufficient to only consider the maximum over vectors of norm 1. (As a matrix represents a linear function, there cannot be a $k\in K$, for which $A(kx)>kA(x)$.)

Comment: @0x90 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom thank me later ~

Comment: http://www.caam.rice.edu/~embree/caam453/lecture2.pdf

Comment: @0x90 what about that? Just some painfully inprecise reading script?

Comment: That is a little bit more relevant in compare to your link into wiki Axiom ... that explains my question :) thanks

Comment: Dont forget to mark your question as answered ;)